# Не могу запустить старый проект

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Собсна говоря, решил посмотреть старый проект, писал его на другой версии рельсов и руби, решил подогнать под новую, не получилось, и наоборот поставил себе через rbenv те самые с которыми я работал, bundle заинсталлил и обновил, вот через rails s получаю такое :

```
/root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing': undefined method `load_defaults' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007f3feb98c330> (NoMethodError)
    from /home/myproject/config/application.rb:12:in `<class:Application>'
    from /home/myproject/config/application.rb:10:in `<module:myproject>'
    from /home/myproject/config/application.rb:9:in `<main>'
    from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `block in server'
    from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
    from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
    from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Как понимаю конфликт с гемами, и он их не видит, облазил весь гугл и стаковер и не нашел ничего толкового.

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43813749/error-undefinded-method-load-defaults-when-trying-to-deploy-app-on-heroku)

Comment: Уже пробовал, увы там другая проблема, там чувак не может новосозданный проект запустить, а у меня старый проект чуть ли не двухгодичной давности, кучу всего перебробовал, появилась безуманая мысль переписать все заново, но так я очень много времени потрачу.

Comment: Видимо у Вас проект был на 4й версии Rails, а пробуете запустить на версии 5. Вот [здесь](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html) статья "от производителя", как осуществлять "переезд". Кроме того, там упоминается метод "load_defaults", который имеется в вашем сообщении об ошибке